# Implementing python data queue buffer

Tags: python

I need to implement a buffer / queue like storage with a given capacity of n that stores n objects and deletes the oldest one if it is full and stores the newest. I bet there must be a defined standard library for this?

Thanks,
EL

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html) module. More specifically the `deque` data structure, which allows you to set a maximum length and automatically drops elements from the end.